# How to use Oddcast with Asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, text-to-speech, espeak

Currently, i'm using Espeak with Asterisk (brazilian's voice), but i'm not getting good results. I found Oddcast and it's really helpful, but coudn't find out yet how to use it with Asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start from app_swift.c code(easy googlable) and extend it for your need.